# How to assign a value to a specific index of an array with Java codeModel

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

How do you employ `com.sun.codemodel` to generate this java statement?

```
constructorArgs[constructorArgIndex] = null;
```

I tried using `com.sun.codemodel.JArrayCompRef` via `component()` however i get
`com.sun.codemodel.JArrayCompRef` is not visible when trying to call method `assign()`

As `com.sun.codemodel.JArrayCompRef` is declared as follows:-

```
final class JArrayCompRef extends JExpressionImpl
```

implements JAssignmentTarget

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: I am creating hundreds of Json mapping java objects and related Junits. Part of this code needs this type of processing constructorArgs[constructorArgIndex] = null; I have had to resort to using directStatements, which doesnt feel correct when using something as powerful as codeModel which has specific classes and interfaces for generating java code associated with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.component()` is available via the `JExpression` interface.  All you need to do is use it via the interface:

```
JExpression expression = ...
expression.component(JExpr.lit(1));
```

This works for the other common expressions in JCodeModel (`JVar`, `JInvocation`) as they all extend `JExpression`.

I ran into a similar problem when trying to use this method and casing the expression to a `JArrayCompRef`.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody else wants to know this is what i endended up doing...

```
final JDefinedClass jDefindedClass = codeModel._class(JMod.PUBLIC, "org.sand.pit", ClassType.CLASS);
final JMethod jmethod = jDefindedClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC, void.class, "testMethod");
final JBlock jblock = jmethod.body();

final JExpression equalsZero = JExpr.lit(0);
final JVar jvarIndex = jblock.decl(JMod.FINAL, codeModel.parseType("int"), "arrayIndex", equalsZero);

final JExpression getArraySize = JExpr.lit(100);
final JClass wildcardClass = codeModel.ref("java.lang.Class");
final JArray newClassArray = JExpr.newArray(wildcardClass, getArraySize);
final JVar jvar = jblock.decl(JMod.FINAL, wildcardClass.array(), "parameterTypes", newClassArray);

final JAssignmentTarget theArray = JExpr.ref("parameterTypes").component(jvarIndex);
jblock.assign(theArray, JExpr._null());
```

This generates the folloiwng java

```
    public void testMethod() {
    final int arrayIndex = 0;
    final Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[ 100 ] ;
    parameterTypes[arrayIndex] = null;
}
```